# How to stick table header(thead) on top while scrolling down the table rows with fixed header(navbar) in bootstrap 3?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css-position, html-table

Bootstrap layout with `fixed-navbar`. Having table with so many rows in body.

**Issue?** As i scroll the page navigation-bar will be there because it is fixed. as i scroll more i want table header to be fixed under navigation-bar and the content of table(table-body) scrolls without scroll bar!

Something like This - [Codepen](http://codepen.io/MeghdadHadidi/pen/rpiav)

---

**Fiddle ** [Bootstrap table](http://jsfiddle.net/5QLPL/)

---

### **[Working Fiddle after referring to the answer!](http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/1362/)**

---

**HTML**

---

```
<!-- Wrap all page content here -->
<div id="wrap">

  <!-- Fixed navbar -->
  <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
              <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Begin page content -->
  <div class="container">
    <div class="page-header">
      <h1>Sticky footer with fixed navbar</h1>
    </div>
    <p class="lead">Pin a fixed-height footer to the bottom of the viewport in desktop browsers with this custom HTML and CSS. A fixed navbar has been added within <code>#wrap</code> with <code>padding-top: 60px;</code> on the <code>.container</code>.</p>

  </div>
<table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Username</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>Otto</td>
            <td>@mdo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Jacob</td>
            <td>Thornton</td>
            <td>@fat</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>Larry</td>
            <td>the Bird</td>
            <td>@twitter</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>Otto</td>
            <td>@mdo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Jacob</td>
            <td>Thornton</td>
            <td>@fat</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>Larry</td>
            <td>the Bird</td>
            <td>@twitter</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>Otto</td>
            <td>@mdo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Jacob</td>
            <td>Thornton</td>
            <td>@fat</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>Larry</td>
            <td>the Bird</td>
            <td>@twitter</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>Otto</td>
            <td>@mdo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Jacob</td>
            <td>Thornton</td>
            <td>@fat</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>Larry</td>
            <td>the Bird</td>
            <td>@twitter</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
</div>

<div id="footer">
  <div class="container">
    <p class="text-muted credit">Example courtesy <a href="http://martinbean.co.uk">Martin Bean</a> and <a href="http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/">Ryan Fait</a>.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should look into [affix](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix)

Comment: This plugin does what you are trying to do http://codepen.io/MeghdadHadidi/pen/rpiav

Comment: how to implement it? @charlie

Comment: Sticky Menu might help you.

Comment: Hey lila! how to do that! please help!

Comment: I guess what you want to do is keep a menu to stay at top while scrolling, right?

Comment: In that case follow @charlie 's link

Comment: This is very simple with the right plugin. See my answer

Comment: If using Bootstrap 4, you can just use [`.sticky-top`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/position/#sticky-top) on all the `th`. If you also have a sticky `nav`, then you will have to add CSS for `table tr th.sticky-top {
 top: 70px;
}`.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Use: https://github.com/mkoryak/floatThead

Docs: http://mkoryak.github.io/floatThead/examples/bootstrap3/

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".sticky-header").floatThead({top:50});
});
```

### DEMO with 2 Tables and Fixed Header:  http://jsbin.com/zuzuqe/1/

*http://jsbin.com/zuzuqe/1/edit*

---

**HTML**

```html
<!-- Fixed navbar -->
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Begin page content -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="page-header">
    <h1>Sticky footer with fixed navbar</h1>
  </div>
  <p class="lead">Pin a fixed-height footer to the bottom of the viewport in desktop browsers with this custom HTML and CSS. A fixed navbar has been added within <code>#wrap</code> with <code>padding-top: 60px;</code> on the <code>.container</code>.</p>
  <table class="table table-striped sticky-header">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Username</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Mark</td>
        <td>Otto</td>
        <td>@mdo</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Jacob</td>
        <td>Thornton</td>
        <td>@fat</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Larry</td>
        <td>the Bird</td>
        <td>@twitter</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Mark</td>
        <td>Otto</td>
        <td>@mdo</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Jacob</td>
        <td>Thornton</td>
        <td>@fat</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Larry</td>
        <td>the Bird</td>
        <td>@twitter</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Mark</td>
        <td>Otto</td>
        <td>@mdo</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Jacob</td>
        <td>Thornton</td>
        <td>@fat</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Larry</td>
        <td>the Bird</td>
        <td>@twitter</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Mark</td>
        <td>Otto</td>
        <td>@mdo</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Jacob</td>
        <td>Thornton</td>
        <td>@fat</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Larry</td>
        <td>the Bird</td>
        <td>@twitter</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <h3>Table 2</h3>

  <table class="table table-striped sticky-header">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>New Table</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Username</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Mark</td>
        <td>Otto</td>
        <td>@mdo</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Jacob</td>
        <td>Thornton</td>
        <td>@fat</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Larry</td>
        <td>the Bird</td>
        <td>@twitter</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Mark</td>
        <td>Otto</td>
        <td>@mdo</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Jacob</td>
        <td>Thornton</td>
        <td>@fat</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Larry</td>
        <td>the Bird</td>
        <td>@twitter</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Mark</td>
        <td>Otto</td>
        <td>@mdo</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Jacob</td>
        <td>Thornton</td>
        <td>@fat</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Larry</td>
        <td>the Bird</td>
        <td>@twitter</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Mark</td>
        <td>Otto</td>
        <td>@mdo</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Jacob</td>
        <td>Thornton</td>
        <td>@fat</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Larry</td>
        <td>the Bird</td>
        <td>@twitter</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

---

**CSS**

```css
body{
  padding-top:50px;
}
table.floatThead-table {
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: none;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: looks great! but not working in my fiddle! trying...! If you can please update my fiddle with your code!

Comment: You need to show the fiddle you tried to get work this is basic stuff. Link to an external resource of the script, loaded after jQuery, if you can't load the external resource, post the full script, then paste in the initialization and CSS. However, Fiddle is a really poor environment compared to JSBin.

Comment: It's Working Great ,,, Take a look my [**jsfiddle.net/ashikjs**](https://jsfiddle.net/ashikjs/ytyhrs84/)

Comment: Thank you. FYI, in the current version it appears the parameter is now simply called `top` instead of `scrollingTop`. It can be either an int, or a function. If a function, it is run again every time `floatThead('reflow')` is called.

Comment: We dont need jQuery for this. -1

Comment: . . . voted down since, although it used to be a great answer, it's now out of date.  There are much [more simple ways](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52008347/8112776) to accomplish this.

Answer (score 108):

This can now be done without JS, just pure CSS. So, anyone trying to do this for modern browsers should look into using [`position: sticky`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Sticky_positioning) instead.

Currently, both [Edge](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/16765952/) and [Chrome have a bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=702927) where `position: sticky` doesn't work on `thead` or `tr` elements, however it's possible to use it on `th` elements, so all you need to do is just add this to your code:

```css
th {
  position: sticky;
  top: 50px;  /* 0px if you don't have a navbar, but something is required */
  background: white;
}
```

Note: you'll need a background color for them, or you'll be able to see through the sticky title bar.

This has [very good browser support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky).

Demo with your code (HTML unaltered, above 5 lines of CSS added, all JS removed):

```css
body {
    padding-top:50px;
}
table.floatThead-table {
    border-top: none;
    border-bottom: none;
    background-color: #fff;
}

th {
  position: sticky;
  top: 50px;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Fixed navbar -->
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"> <span class="icon-bar"></span>
 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
 <span class="icon-bar"></span>

            </button> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>

        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#about">About</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>

                </li>
                <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>

                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Action</a>

                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Another action</a>

                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>

                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>

                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>

                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Begin page content -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="page-header">
         <h1>Sticky Table Headers</h1>

    </div>
    <p class="lead">If the page is tall and all of the table is visible, then it won't stick. Make your viewport short.</p>
    <p class="lead">If the page is tall and all of the table is visible, then it won't stick. Make your viewport short.</p>
    <p class="lead">If the page is tall and all of the table is visible, then it won't stick. Make your viewport short.</p>
    <table class="table table-striped sticky-header">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Username</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Mark</td>
                <td>Otto</td>
                <td>@mdo</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>Jacob</td>
                <td>Thornton</td>
                <td>@fat</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>Larry</td>
                <td>the Bird</td>
                <td>@twitter</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Mark</td>
                <td>Otto</td>
                <td>@mdo</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>Jacob</td>
                <td>Thornton</td>
                <td>@fat</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>Larry</td>
                <td>the Bird</td>
                <td>@twitter</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Mark</td>
                <td>Otto</td>
                <td>@mdo</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>Jacob</td>
                <td>Thornton</td>
                <td>@fat</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>Larry</td>
                <td>the Bird</td>
                <td>@twitter</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Mark</td>
                <td>Otto</td>
                <td>@mdo</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>Jacob</td>
                <td>Thornton</td>
                <td>@fat</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>Larry</td>
                <td>the Bird</td>
                <td>@twitter</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <p class="lead">If the page is tall and all of the table is visible, then it won't stick. Make your viewport short.</p>
    <p class="lead">If the page is tall and all of the table is visible, then it won't stick. Make your viewport short.</p>
    <p class="lead">If the page is tall and all of the table is visible, then it won't stick. Make your viewport short.</p>
    <p class="lead">If the page is tall and all of the table is visible, then it won't stick. Make your viewport short.</p>
    <p class="lead">If the page is tall and all of the table is visible, then it won't stick. Make your viewport short.</p>
    <p class="lead">If the page is tall and all of the table is visible, then it won't stick. Make your viewport short.</p>
    <p class="lead">If the page is tall and all of the table is visible, then it won't stick. Make your viewport short.</p>
     <h3>Table 2</h3>

    <table class="table table-striped sticky-header">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>New Table</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Username</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Mark</td>
                <td>Otto</td>
                <td>@mdo</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>Jacob</td>
                <td>Thornton</td>
                <td>@fat</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>Larry</td>
                <td>the Bird</td>
                <td>@twitter</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Mark</td>
                <td>Otto</td>
                <td>@mdo</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>Jacob</td>
                <td>Thornton</td>
                <td>@fat</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>Larry</td>
                <td>the Bird</td>
                <td>@twitter</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Mark</td>
                <td>Otto</td>
                <td>@mdo</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>Jacob</td>
                <td>Thornton</td>
                <td>@fat</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>Larry</td>
                <td>the Bird</td>
                <td>@twitter</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Mark</td>
                <td>Otto</td>
                <td>@mdo</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>Jacob</td>
                <td>Thornton</td>
                <td>@fat</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>Larry</td>
                <td>the Bird</td>
                <td>@twitter</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice thorough answer for current browsers.

Comment: this doesn't work if you have overflow in the parents

Comment: Doesn't work if the parent is a bootstrap responsive div

Comment: You should be able to add different offsets for each row, no?

Comment: Thank you about the "thead bug" hint!

Comment: I've run into more situations where position sticky fails than it works. If you've got a really simple container go for it but something like highly nested admin templates it never works the way you want it to.

Answer (score 27):

You can do it easily with puse CSS without any kind of JS. you have to add `position: sticky; top: 0; z-index:999;` in `table th` . But this won't work on Chrome Browser but other browser. To work on chrome you have to add those code in `table thead th`

```css
.table-fixed {
  width: 100%;
}

/*This will work on every browser but Chrome Browser*/
.table-fixed thead {
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

/*This will work on every browser*/
.table-fixed thead th {
    position: sticky;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 999;
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<table class="table-fixed">
  <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Table Header 1</th>
        <th>Table Header 2</th>
        <th>Table Header 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Does "This will work on every browser" mean that I _don't_ need the "This will work on every browser but Chrome Browser" version, or that I need _both_ to support (nearly) everything and Chrome?

Comment: I made some working example using this technique. Handling x/y scrolling. https://codepen.io/oswee/pen/xMQJVm

Comment: Works in Chrome but not in Safari

Comment: top: 0 was the trick for me

Answer (score 22):

**Anyone looking for this functionality past 2018**: it's much cleaner to do this with just CSS using position: sticky.

position: sticky doesn't work with some table elements (thead/tr) in Chrome. You can move sticky to tds/ths of tr you need to be sticky. Like this:

```
thead tr:nth-child(1) th {
  background: white;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

I faced the same issue and as majority of the answers indicated, you have to apply position: sticky; and top: 0; ( mostly but can vary if there is a navbar which is fixed as well) to 'th' element. These properties do not apply to thead or tr.

One more thing, if it still doesn't work, you have to look for 'overflow' properties of the parent. If any parent component has an overflow set, i.e. overflow: hidden, then position: sticky just doesn't work. Make sure to remove all such parent properties. Chao!

Comment: Applying `overflow: initial` on my table *wrapper* made it appear on top! That tip was increbily useful! Thanks! **EDIT:** On a further note, I had set `overflow-x: auto` earlier, that's why `initial` did the trick (equivalent of removing it)

Comment: You @Fusseldieb are a true hero! After going through the whole internet for answers, your tip fixed my problem!

Comment: @TimDaubenschütz Happy to know it worked for you :)

Comment: I was having `overflow-x: hidden;` on the body, and that prevented it to work too!

Comment: `overflow` on a parent element was messing me up. This helped. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

```css
.contents {
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
}

table {
  position: relative;
}

th {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="contents">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>colunn 1</th>
        <th>colunn 2</th>
        <th>colunn 3</th>
        <th>colunn 4</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Example 1</td>
        <td>Example 2</td>
        <td>Example 3</td>
        <td>Example 4</td>
        <tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Example 1</td>
            <td>Example 2</td>
            <td>Example 3</td>
            <td>Example 4</td>
            <tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Example 1</td>
                <td>Example 2</td>
                <td>Example 3</td>
                <td>Example 4</td>
                <tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Example 1</td>
                    <td>Example 2</td>
                    <td>Example 3</td>
                    <td>Example 4</td>
                    <tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td>Example 1</td>
                        <td>Example 2</td>
                        <td>Example 3</td>
                        <td>Example 4</td>
                        <tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td>Example 1</td>
                            <td>Example 2</td>
                            <td>Example 3</td>
                            <td>Example 4</td>
                            <tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td>Example 1</td>
                                <td>Example 2</td>
                                <td>Example 3</td>
                                <td>Example 4</td>
                                <tr>
                                  <tr>
                                    <td>Example 1</td>
                                    <td>Example 2</td>
                                    <td>Example 3</td>
                                    <td>Example 4</td>
                                    <tr>
                                      <tr>
                                        <td>Example 1</td>
                                        <td>Example 2</td>
                                        <td>Example 3</td>
                                        <td>Example 4</td>
                                        <tr>
                                          <tr>
                                            <td>Example 1</td>
                                            <td>Example 2</td>
                                            <td>Example 3</td>
                                            <td>Example 4</td>
                                            <tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: can you please explain further how it will work? or convert this code to snipped where the user can see it working.

Comment: I made an example here 
https://codepen.io/pen/?template=poyrbGw

Answer (score 3):

Here is a jsfiddle [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/dPixie/byB9d/3/) (not created by me) that does what you are looking for with pure css in a table.  The thing to note here is the th header is set to a height of 0. Inside each th is and absolute positioned div that puts the header above the table and the scollable div that the table is in.

```
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>#<div>#</div></th>
    <th>First Name<div>First Name</div></th>
    <th>Last Name<div>Last Name</div></th>
    <th>Username<div>Username</div></th>
  </tr>
</thead>
```

Comment: As i scroll the page navigation-bar will be there because it is fixed. as i scroll more i want table header to be fixed under navigation-bar and the content of table(table-body) scrolls without scroll bar!

Comment: Thank you for the answer but i wanted this http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/1360/ it is working now

Answer (score 2):

I accomplished something similar using [jQuery Waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/).

There's a lot of moving parts, and quite a bit of logic (that I hope to get on GitHub some day soon), but essentially what you could do is...

1. Duplicate the table DOM structure in JavaScript and add a class called `fixed`.
2. Add styles for `table.fixed` that make it invisible.
3. Set a way point at the bottom of the header navigation that adds a class called `sticky` to `table.fixed`
4. Add styles for `table.sticky.fixed` that position it just below the navbar and also make just the `thead` content visible. This also has a `z-index` so it is laid above the rest of the content.
5. Add another waypoint, but in the downward scroll event, that removes `.sticky` from the `table.fixed`

You have to duplicate the entire table DOM in order to ensure column widths line up appropriately.

If that sounds really complicated, you might want to try playing around with the DataTables plugin and the FixedHeader extension: https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedheader/

Comment: Thank you for your answer it was helpful! See working Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/1360/

Answer (score 2):

Okku's post worked for me in Edge.
In order to get desired result on the iPhone, I had to use:

```
<thead class="sticky-top">
```

which didn't effect Edge.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have an affix on your header you can use this tricks, add position: relative on your th and change the position in eventListener('scroll')

I have created an example: https://codesandbox.io/s/rl1jjx0o

I use vue.js but you can use this, without vue.js

Comment: I downvoted because of link only answer which in this case meant that the link got broken rendering this answer null and void by SO standard.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for a modern JS framework support like **ReactJS** or **Vue**
try this one instead https://github.com/johngerome/js-sticky-table-headers. Which supports overflow layout.

I'm using this one on my Svelte project.