# fix header on scrolling on html bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Below is my code which I wrote. When I scroll my table, the header goes out of page. In my case, i want that when i scroll, the header always remains on top.

I searched on google many times and tried a lot but could not successfully complete it.

Any help is appreciated.

Below is my code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Striped Rows</h2>

  <table class="table table-striped">

  <div>



    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Email</th>


      </tr>
    </thead>

    </div>


    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssssssssssssssss.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssss.com</td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssssssssssssssss.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssss.com</td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssssssssssssssss.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssss.com</td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssssssssssssssss.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssss.com</td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssssssssssssssss.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssss.com</td>

      </tr><tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssssssssssssssss.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssss.com</td>

      </tr><tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssssssssssssssss.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssss.com</td>

      </tr><tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssssssssssssssss.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssss.com</td>

      </tr><tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssssssssssssssss.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssss.com</td>

      </tr><tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssssssssssssssss.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssss.com</td>

      </tr><tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssssssssssssssss.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssss.com</td>

      </tr><tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssssssssssssssss.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssss.com</td>

      </tr><tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssssssssssssssss.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssss.com</td>

      </tr><tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssssssssssssssss.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssss.com</td>

      </tr><tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssssssssssssssss.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssss.com</td>

      </tr><tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssssssssssssssss.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssss.com</td>

      </tr><tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssssssssssssssss.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssss.com</td>

      </tr><tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssssssssssssssss.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssss.com</td>

      </tr><tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssssssssssssssss.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssss.com</td>

      </tr><tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssssssssssssssss.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssss.com</td>

      </tr><tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssssssssssssssss.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssss.com</td>

      </tr><tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssssssssssssssss.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssss.com</td>

      </tr><tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssssssssssssssss.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssss.com</td>

      </tr><tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssssssssssssssss.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssss.com</td>

      </tr><tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssssssssssssssss.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssss.com</td>

      </tr><tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssssssssssssssss.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssss.com</td>

      </tr><tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssssssssssssssss.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssss.com</td>

      </tr><tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssssssssssssssss.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssss.com</td>

      </tr><tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssssssssssssssss.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssss.com</td>

      </tr><tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssssssssssssssss.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssss.com</td>

      </tr><tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssssssssssssssss.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssss.com</td>

      </tr><tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssssssssssssssss.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssss.com</td>

      </tr><tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssssssssssssssss.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssss.com</td>

      </tr><tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssssssssssssssss.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssss.com</td>

      </tr><tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssssssssssssssss.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssss.com</td>

      </tr><tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssssssssssssssss.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssss.com</td>

      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>



</body>

</html>
```

Regards

Comment: have you even looked through bootstrap's documentation?

Comment: Yes, I have searched a lot. But could not execute it successfully. I need help.

Comment: Check here... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24840074/how-to-stick-table-headerthead-on-top-while-scrolling-down-the-table-rows-with

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scrollable table with fixed header in bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21168521/scrollable-table-with-fixed-header-in-bootstrap)

Answer (score 0):

try this below code , you just need to use bootstrap's `affix`

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
  .affix {
      top: 0;
      width: 100%;
      z-index: 9999 !important;
        background-color: #fff;
  }
</style>

</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Striped Rows</h2>

  <table class="table table-striped">
   
    <thead data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="0">
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Email</th>


      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssssssssssssssss.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssss.com</td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssssssssssssssss.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssss.com</td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssssssssssssssss.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssss.com</td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssssssssssssssss.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssss.com</td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssssssssssssssss.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssss.com</td>

      </tr><tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssssssssssssssss.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssss.com</td>

      </tr><tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssssssssssssssss.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssss.com</td>

      </tr><tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssssssssssssssss.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssss.com</td>

      </tr><tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssssssssssssssss.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssss.com</td>

      </tr><tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssssssssssssssss.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssss.com</td>

      </tr><tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssssssssssssssss.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssss.com</td>

      </tr><tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssssssssssssssss.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssss.com</td>

      </tr><tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssssssssssssssss.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssss.com</td>

      </tr><tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssssssssssssssss.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssss.com</td>

      </tr><tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssssssssssssssss.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssss.com</td>

      </tr><tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssssssssssssssss.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssss.com</td>

      </tr><tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssssssssssssssss.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssss.com</td>

      </tr><tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssssssssssssssss.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssss.com</td>

      </tr><tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssssssssssssssss.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssss.com</td>

      </tr><tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssssssssssssssss.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssss.com</td>

      </tr><tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssssssssssssssss.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssss.com</td>

      </tr><tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssssssssssssssss.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssss.com</td>

      </tr><tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssssssssssssssss.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssss.com</td>

      </tr><tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssssssssssssssss.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssss.com</td>

      </tr><tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssssssssssssssss.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssss.com</td>

      </tr><tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssssssssssssssss.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssss.com</td>

      </tr><tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssssssssssssssss.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssss.com</td>

      </tr><tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssssssssssssssss.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssss.com</td>

      </tr><tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssssssssssssssss.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssss.com</td>

      </tr><tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssssssssssssssss.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssss.com</td>

      </tr><tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssssssssssssssss.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssss.com</td>

      </tr><tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssssssssssssssss.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssss.com</td>

      </tr><tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssssssssssssssss.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssss.com</td>

      </tr><tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssssssssssssssss.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssss.com</td>

      </tr><tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssssssssssssssss.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssss.com</td>

      </tr><tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssssssssssssssss.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>john@examplessssssssss.com</td>

      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi Bhavik, When I run your code, when I scroll down, the header indentation changes, header width changes/collapses and it does'nt  go with the column width. Can you please help

Comment: Also when I load the page and soimply move the scrollbar to the right, the page kind of flickers a lot. This flickering should not happen

Comment: somehow flickering stops when I put a data-offset-top="10" instead of 0. not sure why ? the issue with alignment of header with respect to table data  remains when i scroll down. That still needs to be fixed. Please help

Comment: @DeepikaBansal please visit this link for affix : https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_affix.asp