# Sticky position in table doesn't work in ReactJs

Tags: css, reactjs, sticky

I want to make a table `theader` sticky when I scroll, to always see table's header when scrolling.

I try this but it doesn't do anything.

React render:

```
<table class="table text-center align-middle" style={{ width: this.state.PercentTable }}>
    <thead class="bgColor stickyHeader">
        <tr>
            <th style={{ width: "3%", paddingRight: "0" }}></th>
            <th style={{ width: this.state.PercentCell }}></th>
                {list_1}
        </tr>
     </thead>
     {list_2}
</table>
```

CSS style:

```
.stickyHeader {
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}
```

The table isn't at the top of the view (that's why I want sticky and not fixed).

Here is a working example: [Working example](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_sticky_element)

Thank's for your help.

Comment: Please provide a working example ...There's a button next to the image button to insert your code.

Comment: The position style probably does not work on table headers.

Comment: I tried on a simple div but I got the same result.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24840074/how-to-stick-table-headerthead-on-top-while-scrolling-down-the-table-rows-with

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve this. There is an npm package for this that I recommend that will save you time and energy. Check it out: [react-sticky-table-thead](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-sticky-table-thead)
All you have to do is to wrap a component around your table like:

```
<StickyHeader>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr><th>Head</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr><td>Data</td></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</StickyHeader>
```

Answer (score -1):

make 2 tables. Wrap them into a div. First table use as a header and make it sticky