# show scroll bar with table thead position sticky

Tags: html, css

I have table with thead position sticky, but it make wrapper table container's scroll bar invisible. if make  z-index to -1 scroll will appear, but i dont't want to go it back.

Is there way to make table scroll bar visible ?

```
thead tr th {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

Example:

https://codepen.io/radair2010/pen/qBdQmgd

Without scroll:

[image]

with scroll:
[image]

Comment: With your codepen I can see scroll visible, what exactly you need?

Comment: In chrome browser?

Comment: Yeah I am using chrome. can you attach the screenshot what you mean?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to stick table header(thead) on top while scrolling down the table rows with fixed header(navbar) in bootstrap 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24840074/how-to-stick-table-headerthead-on-top-while-scrolling-down-the-table-rows-with)

Comment: add pictures with scroll and without

Comment: Awais, unfortunately no. I know how to make it fixed, but scroll bar is disables

Comment: @Max I had no other options rather than adding it as answer just to show that your code works with scroll visible, i just added snippet and you can see the scroll or am I missing anything else?

Comment: @Max did you see the result? I will be deleting the code incase if you got what I was trying to say. let me know.

Comment: @Manjuboyz sorry, i missed your answer. Is there any difference in scroll bars when you added z-index: -1 to thead tr th {} css and original code ?